# Jspm error :URIError: URI malformed

Tags: gulp, jspm

I tried running jspm from command line and i get the error:

```
err  URIError: URI malformed
     at decodeURIComponent (native)
     at decodeCredentials (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\jspm-github\github.js:43:15)
     at Object.GithubLocation (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\jspm-github\github.js:84:17)
     at Object.exports.load (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\lib\registry.js:77:56)
     at new RegistryPath (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\lib\config\loader.js:244:33)
     at Config.read (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\lib\config\loader.js:118:26)
     at C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\lib\config.js:94:26
     at tryCatchReject (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\es6-module-loader\dist\es6-module-loader.src.js:1183:30)
     at runContinuation1 (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\es6-module-loader\dist\es6-module-loader.src.js:1142:4)
     at Fulfilled.when (C:\Users\lugassi\Desktop\New folder\UI\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs\node_modules\es6-module-loader\dist\es6-module-loader.src.js:930:4)
```

err  Unable to load registry github

How can I solve this issue? 
Any help will be blessed.

Comment: What is the jspm command you tried running?

Comment: i try to run jspm install

Comment: Did you have any luck yet? I'v got the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083523/how-to-configure-github-credentials-for-jspm-within-appveyor-build-server