# Unauthorized response from GitHub API on Appveyor

Tags: github, jspm, appveyor

We just started with a new project and trying to get CI working via Appveyor. 
It is an `Aurelia` web application so we need `jspm` on the build server.

On my workstation I [configured jspm manually](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/registries.md#creating-a-private-jspm-registry)  as suggested by @guybedford in his answer below and configured my authtoken in appveyor.yml script:

```
  - jspm config registries.github.auth %JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN%
```

Currently my appveyor.yml looks like this, based on the [Auto configuring section from JSPM](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/registries.md#auto-configuring-registries)

```
version: 1.0.{build}
os: Visual Studio 2015
build:
  verbosity: detailed
environment:
  JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN:#token from jspm registry export github (locally)#
install:
  - ps: Set-Culture nl-NL
  - ps: Install-Product node $env:nodejs_version
  - cd src\Web
  - npm uninstall jspm -g
  - npm install -g jspm
  - npm install -g gulp
  - npm install
  - jspm config registries.github.auth %JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN%
  - jspm config registries.github.maxRepoSize 0
  - jspm registry export github #output to see what the registry looks like
  - jspm install -y
  - gulp build
  - cd ..\..
nuget:
  account_feed: true
before_build:
  - dnvm install -r clr -arch x86 1.0.0-rc1-update1
  - dnu restore
  - nuget restore
```

The `jspm install - y` command fails with the error:  `Unauthorized response for GitHub API`.

How do I configure Github credentials properly with JSPM on AppVeyor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contact with the Appveyor team we figured oud that the node version was the problem. 
Installing the stable version of Node works like a charm:

```
ps: Install-Product node stable
```

Answer (score 2):

It is best to take this token from `jspm registry export github` after configuring the credentials locally in order to use the exact same algorithm as jspm instead of doing a manual encoding.

If you really want manual encoding, the auth token actually takes the value of `new Buffer(encodeURIComponent(username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(password)).toString('base64')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took my token after configuring my credentials locally. But it's still giving me unauthorized errors, any other idea's?