# jspm Unauthorized response for GitHub API

Tags: heroku, jspm

I think the below should work based on what I've read but I get an error. I'm surely not expected hard code my password in .netrc. I've ran heroku:set JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN obvs! I've not base64 encoded the token, maybe thats the problem

```
heroku run jspm config registries.github.auth $JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN

$ heroku run jspm init
Running jspm init on test... up, run.7011
ok   Verified package.json at package.json
     Verified config file at frontend/system.config.js
     Looking up loader files...

warn Error on download for github:systemjs/systemjs
     Unauthorized response for GitHub API.
     Use jspm registry config github to reconfigure the credentials, or update them in your ~/.netrc file.

err  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
         at Object.exports.log (/app/node_modules/jspm/lib/ui.js:99:27)
         at /app/node_modules/jspm/lib/core.js:361:8
         at process._tickCallback (node.js:377:9)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35160015/1464069 this answer fixes this problem